# "Does John own" vs. "Is John owning"

Tags: sentence-structure

> Is John own an apartment or a house?

What I thought is to replace ''is'' with ''does''. However, I've been told that we should use gerund instead of it.

> **Does** John own an apartment or a house?
>
> **Is** John own**ing** an apartment or a house?

Comment: Who told you that? "Does John own ..." is natural. The other construction sounds like a non-native speaker talking.

Comment: @Robusto It was on my English exam, which is ''Correct The Mistakes''. My teacher found this truly wrong.

Comment: I'm not talking about the example sentences. I'm talking about where you said you were "told that we should use gerund" there.

Comment: @Robusto According to my English teacher, it ought have been ''Is + verb + ing'' instead of ''Does''. That's what she says.

Comment: @Morata Your English teacher needs an English teacher! It's fine to use the *ing* form in such constructions as: **Is John going/doing....** referring to an action, but not in your example.

Comment: Your English teacher shouldn't be teaching English. "Is John owning..." is wrong as wrong can be. "Does John own... " is correct.

Comment: You either own something or you don't (syntactically, it's not really a "transitional" action manifesting over time). So you have to ask ***Does he own** a house?* - as opposed to something that *can* take time to complete, where you would ask, say, ***Is he buying** a house?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see why "Does John own an apartment or house?" is correct, and the other option is not, it's probably worth converting the sentences into statements, rather than questions:

> John owns an apartment or a house.
>
> *John is owning an apartment or house. (incorrect)

The progressive aspect is used to describe an ongoing action. The verb "to own" already describes an ongoing state of being, rather than a specific action. As a result, we generally don't use the progressive aspect with "to own".

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a good reason why this is true, seeing as how we do use "owning a house" in other, similar, instances, but can't come up with anything better than "because English"

Comment: @Kevin The word “owning” in “owning a house” is a gerund, not the progressive.